# JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet is broken most of the times

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-snippets

I see this for almost all the answers which uses this JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet tool:

[image]

This is how it gets broken when I run the code snippet:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this - all the snippets I have tried work fine. Are you getting any errors in the console? Are you able to access http://stacksnippets.net reliably?

Comment: Also, are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: @Haney - Yes I am!

Comment: @PawanNogariya it's likely the firewall. No issues reported elsewhere in 18 months time and I cannot repro.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for bringing this up. As you indicated that you're behind a corporate firewall, I highly suspect that it is the issue. I cannot reproduce this myself and there are no other widespread reports of this issue. If possible, please try going around the firewall and see if your issue resolves.

Comment: Thanks! Actually the strange thing is within the same corporate firewall I sometimes see the content and sometimes doesn't.